# Mollyguard specific functions (delete-frame)?

Tags: key-bindings, minibuffer, prompt, confirmation

I have recently started using multiple frames regularly. I keep accidentally hitting `C-x 5 0` instead of `C-x 5 o`. I do want to still be able to close frames, but I want an "are you sure? (y/n)" or similar prompt first. Is there anything built-in that can simply wrap a function in to prompt, or am I left inventing my own lisp to do so? I am hoping for something generic that I can easily reuse for other functions/hotkeys. Google gives me numerous but unrelated results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular `y/n` built-in function is `y-or-n-p`.  To write up this answer, I first typed `C-h k C-x 5 0` and saw that it was bound to `delete-frame` with two optional arguments being `FRAME` and `FORCE`; i.e., the `*Help*` buffer displayed (in part):  `(delete-frame &optional FRAME FORCE)`.  From there, I wrote up a simple function and rebound `C-x 5 0` to the new function.  Stringing together functions and rebinding keyboard shortcuts to suit the needs of a particular user is, in my opinion, the Emacs way of doing things.  The variable `ctl-x-5-map` is defined in `subr.el`.

```lisp
(defun my-delete-frame (&optional frame force)
"My doc-string."
  (interactive)
  (if (y-or-n-p "Shall we execute `delete-frame'?:  ")
    (delete-frame frame force)
    (message "my-delete-frame:  You have chosen _not_ to execute `delete-frame'!")))

(define-key ctl-x-5-map "0" 'my-delete-frame)
```

Comment: Nice. That's short enough that I'm not even going to bother trying to make a generic version that takes the function as a callback.